# How do you read the input from subprocess.check_output() in Python?

Tags: python

In my test runner run_tests.py (not suppose to modify)

```
output = subprocess.check_output("python main.py", universal_newlines=True, input="foo bar baz").strip()
```

And in my main.py

```
import sys
import json

print(json.dumps(sys.argv)) # I only get ['main.py']
```

How can I retrieve "foo bar baz" from the input that was passed to the subprocess? I tried checking sys.stdin and no luck there too.

Comment: `sys.argv` contains the command line arguments, not the input. It should be `"python main.py foo bar baz"`

Comment: `sys.stdin` should work to read the input. Show how you tried to use it.

Comment: Why not just import the other module and call a function? This seems really contrived to me.

Answer (score 0):

To pass values that can be accessed from `sys.argv`, they need to be in the command line. The `input` parameter becomes the program's standard input.

```
output = subprocess.check_output(["python", "main.py", "foo", "bar", "baz"], universal_newlines=True).strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are currently passing "foo bar baz" as input in run_tests.py, then printing command line arguments from within main.py. Either passing as input or as command line arguments will work, but you need to pick one. Assuming you are intending to pass alphanumeric values separated by spaces, either will work fine, but if you are passing something more complex like json, it might make more sense to pass it as text input. This would mean you would not need to change run_tests.py.

To pass text as input, try this in main.py:

```
import sys
import json

print(json.dumps(sys.stdin))
```

Edit:

I just realized you are using the json method to dump objects to strings (I had it confused with json.loads). Now that I noticed that, what you are trying to do makes no sense whatsoever. You should try to explain what you are attempting to accomplish (or use loads if you meant to turn a string back into json in main.py).

```
print(json.loads(sys.stdin))
```